# Getting Wrong result in Expandable ListChildView

Tags: android, json, parsing, arraylist

> Good After Noon Everyone!!
>   I am facing one problem in expandable listview > I am not getting exact correct result in expandable listview.
>   I am Getting repeated child in every ListGroupElement.
>   I am getting result in this format:

1. Car

   1. New
   2. Cat
2. Animal

   1. New -----------------repeating
   2. Cat

This is my json format:

```
  {
    "status": 1,
    "category": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "category_name_en": "car",
            "category_name_ar": "car",
            "description_en": "",
            "description_ar": "",
            "day": "monday,tuesday,wednesday,thursday,friday,saturday,sunday",
            "status": "A",
            "created_at": "Sep 4 2017 5:39 PM",
            "updated_at": "Sep 4 2017 5:39 PM",
            "sub_category": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "sub_category_name_en": "**Audi**",
                    "sub_category_name_ar": "Audi",
                    "sub_description_en": "",
                    "sub_description_ar": "",
                    "status": "A",
                    "created_at": "Sep 4 2017 5:40 PM",
                    "updated_at": "Sep 4 2017 5:40 PM"
                },
                {
                    "id": 4,
                    "sub_category_name_en": "**New**",
                    "sub_category_name_ar": "New",
                    "sub_description_en": "",
                    "sub_description_ar": "",
                    "status": "A",
                    "created_at": "Sep 4 2017 7:15 PM",
                    "updated_at": "Sep 4 2017 7:15 PM"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "category_name_en": "Animal",
            "category_name_ar": "Animal",
            "description_en": "",
            "description_ar": "",
            "day": "monday,tuesday,wednesday,thursday,friday,saturday,sunday",
            "status": "A",
            "created_at": "Sep 4 2017 6:49 PM",
            "updated_at": "Sep 4 2017 6:49 PM",
            "sub_category": [
                {
                    "id": 2,
                    "sub_category_name_en": "**Dogs**",
                    "sub_category_name_ar": "Dogs",
                    "sub_description_en": "",
                    "sub_description_ar": "",
                    "status": "A",
                    "created_at": "Sep 4 2017 6:50 PM",
                    "updated_at": "Sep 4 2017 6:50 PM"
                },
                {
                    "id": 3,
                    "sub_category_name_en": "**Cat**",
                    "sub_category_name_ar": "Cat",
                    "sub_description_en": "",
                    "sub_description_ar": "",
                    "status": "A",
                    "created_at": "Sep 4 2017 6:51 PM",
                    "updated_at": "Sep 4 2017 6:51 PM"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
```

> i want result in this format

1. Car

   1. Audi
   2. New
2. Animal

   1. Cat
   2. dogs

**This is my parsing**

```
     private ArrayList<ModelGroup> modelgroup = null;
    private ArrayList<ModelChild> modelchild = null;

    private ArrayList<ArrayList<ModelChild>> ListChildXXXXXXXXX= null;
 ModelGroup LT = null;
                    ModelChild CT = null;

                    String response = result.getResult().toString();
                    JSONObject jsonRoot = new JSONObject(response);
                    JSONArray jsonArray = jsonRoot.getJSONArray("category");

                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                        LT= new ModelGroup();

                        JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        LT.setCat_name(jsonObject.getString("category_name_en"));
                      //  LT.setCat_id(jsonObject.getString("id"));
                        modelgroup.add(LT);
                        JSONArray jsonArray1 = jsonObject.getJSONArray("sub_category");
                        for (int j = 0; j < jsonArray1.length(); j++) {
                            CT = new ModelChild();

                            JSONObject jsonObject2 = null;

                            jsonObject2 = jsonArray1.getJSONObject(j);

                            CT.setSub_category_name_en(jsonObject2.getString("sub_category_name_en"));

                        }

                     //get(i).get(i).add(CT);

                        modelchild.add(CT);

                            ListChildXXXXXXXXX.add(modelchild);

                    }
```

Please Correct me where i am doing wrong,
Thanks for helping.

Comment: Did you try to debug? I mean what do you have in ListChildXXXXXXXXX after you finish thie loops? Because as I can see now this is not Android problem. At least I can't see any android code.

Comment: in ListChildXXXXXXXXX all Chid Are added@AndreyDobrikov

Comment: So basically you have at the end two lists: modelgroup ("Car", "Animal") and ListChildXXXXXXXXX(("Audi", "New") , ("Cat", "Dog"))?

Comment: please lets talk at this chat https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154433/room-for-andrey-dobrikov-and-harshal-deshmukh